# Default permissions for C:\Documents and Settings

Tags: windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

I didn't realise that one shouldn't change the permissions on `C:\Documents and Settings` until after I'd already changed it.

I want to prevent future problems by restoring the default permissions.

What are the default permissions on `C:\Documents and Settings`? Any gotchas in restoring them?

Comment: I'm guessing it's Windows 7? Also, how many different user accounts are on that computer? Is yours the only one or are there multiple?

Comment: @wrecclesham It's tagged 10, and I want the default permissions which is not affected by the number of users.

Comment: I get it now. You were just editing the legacy NTFS junction point that points to C:\Users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you still have ownership, as you would have had to have taken ownership in order to modify permissions. These are the defaults:
[image]
The Advanced view of the Deny entry looks like this:
[image]
Here's the basic view of the Allow Everyone entry:
[image]

After setting the permissions, restore ownership to SYSTEM and you should be good.

Comment: I needed to first apply the Allow permissions, then add the Deny one last. I changed the owner last of all.